# canot get a working certificate on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, docker-registry

Hi i'm new on kubernetes and i'm trying to get a docker registry working on a kubernetes cluster.

I created a cluster on 3 nodes with vagrant in my laptop and kubespray.
Then followed this tutorial :

> https://www.civo.com/learn/set-up-a-private-docker-registry-with-tls-on-kubernetes

My first error at the end was that my certificate x509 was valid for "ingress.local" and not myDomainName.com in my ingress.yaml file. 
So i tested to reinstall with "- host: ingress.local" instead of "- host: myDomainName.com" in the ingress.yaml file.

But now i'm getting :

> Error response from daemon: Get https://ingress.local/v2/: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority

I do not have a domain name so to test i added this mapping on my hosts file :

```
192.168.50.11 ingress.local
```

Where 192.168.50.11 is a node ip

and finally when i run

> kubectl get cert -n default
>   i'm gettind
>    No resources found.

I really don't know where to start to investigate

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

`x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` means the certificate authority which signed is not known. Letsencrypt needs a valid registered domain because it will validate the domain ownership and then issue the certificate valid for that domain only. Since you don't have a valid registered domain this is not working.

Comment: Thanks 
Si i purchased a domain name and replaced in the ingress.yaml ans still having the same error. But now when i run kubectl get cert -n default i have a response with the Ready : false

Comment: after that it worked or still having issue?

Comment: no, same issue, the only difference is that "kubectl get cert -n default" gives me now "mydomain.org-cert   False   databoxflow.org-cert   5m21s"

Comment: should my cluster be accessible from outside ? because it is not .

Comment: well..you need to access it from somewhere..not necessarily via public internet

Comment: from my browser i can access : databoxflow.org because i added in my host file "192.168.50.11 databoxflow.org"
But getting NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID